# Custom /page/2/ template (different from index.php)

Tags: pages, homepage

I'm trying to create a custom page 2 template that's different from the main index.php. For example, the main index page would display the latest news + a lot of features like a magazine. When readers click to read on to page 2, 3, 4 etc of the news posts, they are taken to a more regular news page. Kinda like something on theverge.com (at the bottom, click "next page" and see what I mean).

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this? I know it's possible to create archive pages for categories and tags, but I'm not sure how to do it for the index.php.

Thanks!

Comment: At least, you should disclaime that you are cross-posting... http://stackoverflow.com/q/11285094/1287812

Comment: @Bill if one of the answers below worked for you, please MARK it as the answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [`is_paged()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged) conditional inside `index.php` to load two separate templates containing your layouts. Something like this:

```
if ( is_paged() ):
   get_template_part( 'content', 'first-page' );
else:
   get_template_part( 'content', 'paged' );
endif;
```

Assuming you have two templates, `content-first-page.php` and `content-paged.php`.

**Edit:** If you just want a different template for part of your index page, try this:

```
if ( !is_paged() ):
   get_template_part( 'content', 'middle' );    
endif;
```

Put that wherever you want the extra template to load.

Comment: Thanks man, that seems to have done the job. I don't think the index and subsequent pages are that different, the index page basically has an extra section of content before the footer. Is there a way of including this section (e.g. "middle.php") via php include only on the main index page and not the other pages (page 2, 3, 4 etc.)? Thanks again!

Comment: You can use my code for that purpose with a few modifications.

Answer (score 3):

@Joseph's answer is probably what you're after. But if the first and subsequent pages are going to be sufficiently different so as to require a complete different template you can hook into the `template_include` filter.

```
add_action('template_include','wpse57122_change_on_p2');
function wpse57122_change_on_p2( $template ){
    if( is_front_page() && is_paged() ){
        $template = locate_template(array('archive.php','index.php'));
    }
    return $template;
}
```

This alters the default template used for pages 2 and higher of the 'front page' (see [`is_front_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) and [`is_paged()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged)). The [`locate_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) searches the (child and parent) theme for the given templates - in the order given to it. In this example, it will use `archive.php` for pages 2 and above-  if that template doesn't exist, it will use `index.php` instead.